# PyCharm not fixing indentation when code is pasted

Tags: python, pycharm

I have some python code:

```
def sameDay(date, dayOfWeek, week, year):    

theDay = datetime.fromtimestamp(
mktime(time.strptime("%s %s %s %s %s" % ("12", "00", dayOfWeek, week, year), "%H %M %w %W %Y")))
return theDay.date() == date.date()


def zeroPadding(string):    

integer = int(string)
if integer < 10:
return "0" + str(integer)
else:
return str(integer)
```

When I paste these lines into PyCharm, the indentation is not fixed and I can't compile the code. I have tried using the `"Reformat Code"` option, but that does not work. I have checked the "Smart indent pasted lines" with no results either.

How do I fix the indentation, so I can compile my program in PyCharm?

[Here is a snapshot of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2VSn.png)

Comment: "Compile" doesn't exist in Python. There's only a prepare stage of the modules or imported files to generate pre-optimised code, the rest happens during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible for an editor to do this.

Indentation in Python has *meaning*. Indented code denotes a block in the syntax of the language, and changes how the code executes. It's not possible to look at the code and discern the meaning of it once the indentation has been lost.

We can make educated guesses as humans, but automating this is not possible. Reformat code naturally does nothing as indentation isn't formatting in Python. I imagine 'Smart indent' just changes from tabs to spaces or the reverse depending on your project settings.

In your example - assuming it's all at the top level of a module and thanks to the `return` statements/the lack of much nesting, it's mostly unambiguous, however it is possible the second function could be nested in the first.

E.g:

```
if x < 1:
...
if y < 2:
...
else:
...
```

Could be either:

```
if x < 1:
    ...
    if y < 2:
        ...
else:
    ...
```

or:

```
if x < 1:
    ...
    if y < 2:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Loss of indentation in Python is like deleting random characters from source code in any language. You have lost some of the code, and will need to reconstruct it using your understanding of the code.